# ASP.Net Core Global Authorization Filter Based on HttpVerb

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, http-verbs

I'm trying to create an easy policy, which will Allow anonymous Requests for All HttpGet Gets by Default and Authorize for anything else (put, patch, post, delete etc.)

Currently I'm requiring authorization everywhere like so:

```
var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicy)))
```

But in reality I want to do something like this:

```
var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser(opt => opt.DesinationCalls.Where(m =>
             false == m.Attributes.Any(x => x == "HttpGet"))).Build();
```

I'm do not want to have to remember add attributes to my controllers,
Does anyone know how I can filter my default authorization policy by Http Verb?

Comment: What RequireAuthenticatedUser does is just adding a DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement to the policy. Maybe you can create your own requirement which inherits from AuthorizationHandler<T>